# Google Admin API - User Phone Number

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to fetch phone number of the domain users using Admin api,but in response always users phone number is empty.

Do I have to set any specific scope for it ? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you fetching the user's phone number? Can you show us.

Comment: I have just followed steps from (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users) using google api client for PHP(https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/php)